# Greatest integer of 1-x

Tags: functions, special-functions

In interval x lying between -1/2 to +1/2, what will be the greatest integer of 1-x? The answer is -[x] ,i.e. negative of greatest integer of x but how?

Comment: Try splitting it into cases from $(-\frac12 ,0)$ and $(0,\frac 12)$ what values does $1-x$ have there?

Comment: I can't parse what you mean in your question: if $\;-\frac12<x<\frac12\;$ , then the supremum value of $\;1-x\;$ is $\;\frac32\;$ , so the answer must be $\;1\;$ ...

Comment: Yes , answer should be 1 or 0. But in some solving , my book is taking it equal to negative of greatest integer of x

Comment: @KaSikh I just can't understand what the floor function has to do with all this, unless they want you to get used to use it...And even then: is $\;x\;$ in this case a variable a or a fixed, constant number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use the more modern notation $\lfloor y\rfloor$ to denote
the greatest integer less than or equal to $y.$

Your book appears to have a slight error. In the case where $x=0,$
we have $1-x = 1$ and therefore $\lfloor 1-x\rfloor = 1,$
but $-\lfloor x\rfloor = -(0) = 0.$

In all other cases, the claim would be correct:

- If $0<x<\frac12,$ then $0 < 1-x < 1$ and therefore $\lfloor 1-x\rfloor = 0 = -\lfloor x\rfloor.$
- If $-\frac12 < x < 0,$ then $\lfloor x\rfloor = -1$ and $1 < 1-x < 2,$
  so $\lfloor 1-x\rfloor = 1 = -\lfloor x\rfloor.$

However, a statement that is true for all of the interval 
$\left[-\frac12, \frac12\right]$ **except at** $0$
and **is false at** $0$
is not a statement that is true for all of the interval 
$\left[-\frac12, \frac12\right].$

Comment: 0 is point of discontinuity , so I think we should not discuss on it

Comment: A little mistake in above answer. [1-x]=1 in last case

Comment: @KaSikh Thanks for pointing out the sign error so I could fix it. It is also true that for many purposes (such as differentiation or integration), the value at the point of discontinuity doesn't matter, and we could make the book's substitution.